# Can't dismiss a progress dialog

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, progressdialog

I have a `ProgressDialog` that is displayed while I fetch data from parse. And it should dismiss when its done, but it doesn't.

```
private ProgressDialog progress;
mainAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Tittle","Message", true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, Exception e) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

I've tried working with threads, I've used `progress.cancel()` and `progress.hide()` but for some reason the `ProgressDialog` does not close and stays on screen even after the `dismiss` comand.

Comment: Add logging to `onLoaded()` to make sure it's getting into that code.

Comment: I can assure you it does, I have a `Toast` there and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Tittle","Message", true);
```

actually is

```
    public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
}
```

and it call this method

```
    public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
        boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

so the `cancelable` is `false`. Try to use

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Tittle","Message", true, true);
```

Hope it helps.